# what does the ampersand operator do in python in conditional expressions?

Tags: python

I just stumbled upon this snippet

```
if len(x_) &gt;= no_peaks:
```

what does that mean?

it resembles an and from other languages but I cannot quite make sense of it

Comment: That's a syntax error. And any python interpreter could've told you that.

Comment: `&gt;=` is very likely mangled HTML, and is supposed to be `>=` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of a badly-configured HTML escaping tool which somehow managed to escape the code *twice*. It's supposed to be `>=`.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a syntax error.
To answer your question however, the `&` character performs a bitwise and operation if used alone [as seen in the documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-16). 
If used in conjunction with an equal sign it performs the same operation as part of an [augmented assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#index-14).